# is allocator_traits::deallocate a valid shared_ptr deleter

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, allocator

I guess this question is really about the design of `std::allocator_traits` and providing a custom allocator. If I want to construct a `std::shared_ptr<>` using a custom allocator, can I use std::allocator_traits?

Basically, is this correct?

```
WidgetAllocator allocator;
std::shared_ptr<Widget> widget(allocator.allocate(), std::allocator_traits<WidgetAllocator>::deallocate);
```

Comment: Is `WidgetAllocator` really an allocator? Allocators are supposed to take an argument to the `allocate` function, specifying the requested number of bytes.

Comment: If it's not an allocator, it's because I don't understand the `std::allocator_traits` pattern. The crux of my question is how to make something that's compatible with both `std::allocator<>` and `std::allocator_traits<WidgetAllocator>`, and frankly this article https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator tells me specifically what's _required_, but not how to use it with `std::allocator_traits` or how to interoperate with `std::allocator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically, is this correct?
>
> ```
> std::shared_ptr<Widget> widget(allocator.allocate(), std::allocator_traits<WidgetAllocator>::deallocate);
> ```

That's not correct.

Firstly, an allocator is not guaranteed to have a nullary `allocate` member function.

OK, let us assume that `WidgetAllocator` does provide such overload, although that's not quite typical for an allocator. But more importantly, `std::allocator_traits::deallocate` is not callable with a `Widget*`. Its argument list is `( Alloc& a, pointer p, size_type n )`.

> So what's the recommended use of allocator_traits?

You should use `std::allocator_traits` whenever you want to use one of the *optional* features of an allocator such as `Alloc::is_always_equal`, and the allocator that you want to use either does not provide the optional feature, or the allocator is a template argument, and you want to support all allocators regardless of whether they provide optional features.

`std::allocator_traits` provides default implementation for the optional features of an allocator.

> Should I be invoking methods on the allocator directly?

You *can* invoke member functions directly, if the allocator that you use provides them, or in generic case, if they are non-optional. Invoking the members directly is not necessary though, you can always use allocator traits instead.

Comment: So what's the recommended use of allocator_traits? Should I be using it to perform allocation with my custom allocator? Should I be invoking methods on the allocator directly?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!